# How to support variable in include()?

Tags: php, include

I have a simple php file with an include command which does not work in my case.

```
$rootfolder = 'www.example.com/new/';
include $rootfolder.'_header.php';
```

My _header.php file is in www.example.com/new/, but is not included. I have seen instructions, telling that this should work.

When I check my include path with

```
echo $rootfolder.'_header.php';
```

it works perfectly and directs to the correct file: "www.example.com/new/_header.php"

But why isn't it working for me in the include line?

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what the error  you are getting?

Comment: where your simple php file located?

Comment: You need to use absolute path not relative path

Comment: use an absolute path rather than a url. ie `$rootfolder='c:/wwwroot/inc/'; include $rootfolder . '_header.php';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong root. try figuring out the absolute path to the file using `realpath`:

```
$rootfolder = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])."/new/";
include $rootfolder.'_header.php';
```

Or use `__FILE__` to echo the file path from `_header.php` to see whats it absolute path

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "$path";
```

Comment: I would highlight @tluebke uses wrong conception trying to include file by URL instead of local filesystem's path. Some time ago it("remote include") worked but was claimed as a bad practice because of creating security issues.

Comment: @skyboyer: My problem was that I have different files in different subfolders, but wanted to have the same heading in all files which not need to be edited in every file, depending on their local path on the web server. I wanted to solve this problem by using the absolute path for the include.

Comment: @tluebke so is  www.example.com real folder on the disk not just domain name?

Comment: www.example.com was the domain name only, but I was confused since I thought that this "absolute path" might work.
The path name is "/mnt/userid/example.com" with wich the include() works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

there is kinds of technique to access file form anywhere i give some of that

if you want access from other folder then do this below

below folder hierarchy see care fully

-root

- css
- include

  - _header.php
- js
- admin

  - manager.php
- index.php

if you include _header.php in index.php then

```
include "include/_header.php";
```

if you include _header.php in manager.php from admin folder then

```
include "../include/_header.php";
```

hear tow .(dot) indicate go back one step in hierarchy

if not any one you ans then please ask again  in comment

Comment: Actually, this was not the problem. Both files were in the same folder, but my approach was wrong.

Comment: then what you want exactly @tluebke

Comment: AnatPort answered my question.